# Copying std::vector of Pointers to a std::list

Tags: c++, algorithm, lambda, stl

I have a function:

```cpp
std::list<Song> SongCollection::getSongsForArtist(std::string artistName) const {
    std::list<Song>  songs;
    auto addArtistSongs = [=](Song* song) {
        if (song->m_artist == artistName) {
            return song;
        }
    };
    std::copy_if(m_songCollection.begin(), m_songCollection.end(), std::back_inserter(songs), addArtistSongs);  

    return songs;
}
```

It's supposed to add `Song` objects to `list<Song>` based on my lambda function.

The `m_collection` is my vector of pointers, which holds the `Song`s that could potentially be copied into the `std::list` based on the `artistName`.

Tried `back_inserter` but that doesn't seem to work.

ERROR:

> Error     C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'sdds::Song *const ' (or there is no acceptable conversion);

Thought I had to make a copy constructor/assignment, but that didn't work, either.

Answer (score 3):

Your lambda doesn't have a consistent return value... And `std::copy_if` expects a lambda that returns bool.

```cpp
auto addArtistSongs = [=](Song* song) -> bool {
  return song->m_artist == artistName;
}
```

Additionally, shouldn't you be returning a list of **pointers** to Song?

```cpp
std::list<Song *> songs;
```

Comment: Hm, okay yes, I didnt noticed that I missed the trailing return type. But that's where I am confused, the function  that I am working on specifically asks to return a std::list<Song>.

Comment: So you can't directly copy a container of `Song *` into a container of `Song`. You'd need to dereference it along the way. In which case you can't use `std::copy_if`